# flask_mail Message instance is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, celery-task, flask-mail

I am trying to run this very simple flask/celery app:

```
  @celery.task
    def send_async_email(msg):
        with app.app_context():
            mail.send(msg)

    @celery.task(bind=True)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

    def index():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('index.html', email=session.get('email', ''))
        email = request.form['email']
        session['email'] = email

        msg = Message('Hello from Flask',
                      recipients=[request.form['email']])
        msg.body = 'This is a test email sent from a background Celery task.'
        print type(msg)
        print dir(msg)
        print 'msg.send'
        print msg.send
        print 'msg'
        print msg

        if request.form['submit'] == 'Send':

            send_async_email.delay(msg)
            flash('Sending email to {0}'.format(email))
        else:

        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

but it is not working because the instance of this Message class is not json serializable, which does not seem to be the case:

```
    msg.send
    <bound method Message.send of <flask_mail.Message object at 0x7ffa94cd0290>>
    msg
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Subject: Hello from Flask
    From: flask@example.com

    EncodeError: <flask_mail.Message object at 0x7ffa94cd0290> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Relevant https://github.com/inveniosoftware/invenio-accounts/pull/84/commits/0a3caef5c1ae669074287fcbefc62c932e4b5d82

Answer (score 3):

Celery requires that objects passed via the broker be straightforwardly serializable. `flask_mail.Message` objects are not. You should change the method signature of `send_async_email(msg)` to accept a simple JSON compatible object. That is, a raw string, int, dictionary of those, or something similar. You should then move all the logic for `Message` (from instantiation to sending) inside that method.

For example:

```
@celery.task
def send_async_email(message_details):
    with app.app_context():
        msg = Message(message_details['subject'],
                      message_details['recipients'])
        msg.body = message_details['body']
        print type(msg)
        print dir(msg)
        print 'msg.send'
        print msg.send
        print 'msg'
        print msg
        mail.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that by simply setting the serialization and adding changing the default  works like a charm.

```
app.config.update(
accept_content=['json','pickle']
)
```

then,

```
@celery.task(serializer='pickle')
def send_async_email(msg):
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to downgrade your flask-mail version to 0.9.0.

You can do it with this command:

```
pip uninstall Flask-Mail
pip install Flask-Mail==0.9.0
```